# Combine two arrays of objects into one array for use in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-visualization, underscore.js

Before I start, yes I googled like crazy and read many answers on SO, but I just wasn't able to accomplish what needs to be done so I'm seeking help.

I have this problem that I just cannot solve. I have to display some data in a Google Annotation chart. The data I'm getting is in this format:

```
var arr1 = [{
    timestamp: "1505735024496", value1: 2
},
{
    timestamp: "1505815355920", value1: 5
},
.....
]

var arr2 = [{
    timestamp: "1505383687151", value2: 1
},
{
    timestamp: "1505485417374", value2: 3
},
.....
]
```

The end goal here is to combine these two arrays of objects into an array of arrays like this:

```
var final = [
[new Date(YYYY, DD, MM), value1, value2], 
[new Date(YYYY, DD, MM), value1, value2], 
...
]
```

as per instructions on the [Google Charts documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart) for that particular chart.

I only managed to convert timestamps to full dates with corresponding values for those dates, but that again gives me array of objects where I just converted the timestamp to a date and nothing much changed.

```
var indexesArr1 = arr1.map(function (obj) {
  return obj.timestamp;
});

var arr1New = arr1.map(function (obj) {
  var index = indexesArr1.indexOf(obj.timestamp);
  return { date: moment(parseInt(obj.timestamp)).format('YYYY, MM, DD'), value1: index > -1 ? arr1[index].value : obj.value };
});
```

The real problem here is that arr1 and arr2 don't have to be the same length (and probably won't be most of the time) and since this chart will display data over time, it's important to populate every date with both value1 and value2, even thought one of those values might not be explicitly returned for that particular day. And one more thing would be to remove all instances of duplicate dates, but leave the last one, since that one represents the last logged value for that particular date.

I've used Moment.js to easily convert timestamps to desired format('YYYY, DD, MM'), but I just cannot do all the data manipulation properly.

Use of [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) is allowed since I know it has some great utility functions for these types of problems, but I just wasn't able to solve it (don't have that much experience with it to be honest) and I know there are people here with more knowledge than me so I'm seeking help.

Thank you in advance for taking your time to answer this.

P.S. I would link to Moment.js but I don't have enough reputation to post more than 2 links currently.

Comment: Here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp does that help?

Comment: Anyway I don't really get what you are trying to do... I guess something like an histogram?

Comment: @YvonneReinhardt No, just concating the arrays is not the thing I'm looking for. Look at the example from the google chart documentation that I linked to. Not exactly a histogram, but value timeline I would say. Something you would find on financial charts for example where you can see USD/EUR value over periods of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recommend creating two google data tables from the arrays...

```
var arr1 = [{
  timestamp: "1505735024496", value1: 1
}, {
  timestamp: "1505735034496", value1: 2
}, {
  timestamp: "1505815355920", value1: 5
}];

var arr2 = [{
  timestamp: "1505383687151", value2: 1
}, {
  timestamp: "1505485417374", value2: 3
}];

var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr1.map(function (row) {
  return [new Date(parseInt(row.timestamp)), row.value1];
}), true);

var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr2.map(function (row) {
  return [new Date(parseInt(row.timestamp)), row.value2];
}), true);
```

then you can join the data tables on the timestamp

```
var dataJoin = google.visualization.data.join(
  data1,
  data2,
  'full',
  [[0, 0]],
  [1],
  [1]
);
```

the join will use `null` values for each column where the dates do not match,
which can be replaced with zeroes using a data view

AnnotationChart doesn't support option `interpolateNulls`,
other charts, you could leave the nulls

to address missing and multiple dates,
use data table method `getColumnRange` to find the min and max dates in the table

then starting with the min date, until the max date,
use data table method `getFilteredRows` to check for each date in between
use only the date portion, drop the time values

if the date doesn't exist, add a new row
if date exists multiple times, delete all but last

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['annotationchart', 'table']
}).then(function () {

  // date formatter
  var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
  });

  // original arrays
  var arr1 = [{
    timestamp: "1505735024496", value1: 1
  }, {
    timestamp: "1505735034496", value1: 2
  }, {
    timestamp: "1505815355920", value1: 5
  }];
  var arr2 = [{
    timestamp: "1505383687151", value2: 1
  }, {
    timestamp: "1505485417374", value2: 3
  }];

  // create google data table for each array
  var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr1.map(function (row) {
    return [new Date(parseInt(row.timestamp)), row.value1];
  }), true);
  var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr2.map(function (row) {
    return [new Date(parseInt(row.timestamp)), row.value2];
  }), true);

  // join data tables
  var dataJoin = google.visualization.data.join(
    data1,
    data2,
    'full',
    [[0, 0]],
    [1],
    [1]
  );
  // sort join data table to ensure latest date is last
  dataJoin.sort([{column: 0}]);

  // one day time
  var oneDay = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

  // get date range
  var dateRange = dataJoin.getColumnRange(0);

  // drop time values from min and max dates
  var begDate = new Date(dateRange.min.getFullYear(), dateRange.min.getMonth(), dateRange.min.getDate());
  var endDate = new Date(dateRange.max.getFullYear(), dateRange.max.getMonth(), dateRange.max.getDate());

  // check each date
  for (var iDate = begDate.getTime(); iDate <= endDate.getTime(); iDate = iDate + oneDay) {
    // find date
    var findDate = new Date(iDate);
    var dateRows = dataJoin.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 0,
      test: function (rowValue) {
        var rowDate = formatDate.formatValue(rowValue);
        var testDate = formatDate.formatValue(findDate);
        return (rowDate === testDate);
      }
    }]);

    // getFilteredRows will return array of row indexes
    switch (dateRows.length) {
      // add row
      case 0:
        dataJoin.addRow([findDate, null, null]);
        break;

      case 1:
        break;

      // remove all duplicates except the last row index found
      default:
        for (var iRow = dateRows.length - 2; iRow >= 0; iRow = iRow - 1) {
          dataJoin.removeRow(dateRows[iRow]);
        }
    }
  }
  dataJoin.sort([{column: 0}]);

  // replace null values with zeroes
  var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(dataJoin);
  dataView.setColumns([0, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 1) || 0;
    },
    label: 'y0',
    type: 'number'
  }, {
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 2) || 0;
    },
    label: 'y1',
    type: 'number'
  }]);

  // draw annotation chart
  var containerChart = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(containerChart);
  chart.draw(dataView);

  // draw table for testing purposes, "see" the data
  var containerTable = document.getElementById('table_div');
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(containerTable);
  table.draw(dataView);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
<div id="table_div"></div>
```

Comment: Seriously, you are a life saver. It works. Now I just need to study this and populate these days that have value1/value2 as '0' with the value from the day before since it is a timeline, value just doesn't drop to zero. But still, thank you so much, I would have never did this on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be a direct answer to your question, but have you ever thought of using the timestamp as your object key? It would be way more performant to use it like that than to loop over it when assigning new values to existing objects.

e.g.

```
let obj1 = {
    '34123812371293': 2,
  '12314981391230': 3,
}
let obj2 = {
    '13812381238123' : 1,
    '19312930812930' : 3,
  '12314981391230': 100,
}

let combinedObj = Object.assign({}, obj1);
Object.keys(obj2).map(o2 => {
    if(combinedObj[o2] != undefined){
    combinedObj[o2] += obj2[o2];
  }else{
    combinedObj[o2] = obj2[o2];
  }
});
console.log(combinedObj);
```

That way when you pull in new data you can directly compare the new datas object key to your existing object and increase the value or add a new key pair.

https://jsfiddle.net/z23xeaxm/

Comment: Thank you for your input, will keep this in mind, but @WhiteHat already gave his answer which is actually a direct answer to my question.